# C Pointers Past Paper

Tags: c, pointers

I'm looking at a past paper for a course I'm doing at university, and there is always a question about C pointers.

I reckon I have a reasonable grasp of how they work, however this is the question that is confusing me:

```
Consider running the C program fragment:


int x[4] = {0,2,4,6};
int *y;
y = &x[2];
*(x + 2) = y[1] + 1;

What is the value of the expression *y afterwards?
(a) 2
(b) 4
(c) 5
(d) 7
(e) 8
```

Now, in the answers to said question, it says the answer is `d`.

I'm super confused, seeing as:

1. The value of x is not declared, so I'd have thought it would be impossible to evaluate `x+2`
2. `y` isn't an array, so how can `y[1]` be evaluated?

Why is `7` the correct answer here?

Comment: *(x+2) and x[2] are the same for the compiler. y[1] is the same as *(y+1). since y is the same memory location as x+2, then (x+2)+1 is pointing at 6 or x[3]. add one to it becomes 7. and that it assigned to x[2], where y is pointing

Comment: Beat me to it. Good explanation @jcjunction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break it down:

**int x[4] = {0,2,4,6};**

```
x [0] = 0
x [1] = 2
x [2] = 4
x [3] = 6
```

**int *y;** Pointer to an integer so y could point to any location in x

```
x [0] = 0       // <-- y ?
x [1] = 2       // <-- y ?
x [2] = 4       // <-- y ?
x [3] = 6       // <-- y ?
```

**y = &x[2];** Now we have specified that y points to x[2]

```
x [0] = 0
x [1] = 2
x [2] = 4       // <-- y (or y[0])
x [3] = 6
```

***(x + 2)** This is the same as x[2] so:
**x[2] = y[1] + 1;**

```
x [0] = 0
x [1] = 2
x [2] = 4       // <-- x[2]  
x [3] = 6       // <-- y[1]
```

**y[1] is 6, so y[1] + 1 = 7**

Note that y[1] is the same as *(y + 1). We take the address y points too, add to it the size of one integer and obtain the contents of what it now points to.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is the 4-element array. `*x` references the first element in that array, and `*(x + 2)` references the 3rd element.

`*y` points at index 2 (3rd element) in the `x` array `(y = &x[2])`

the final assignment sets the 3rd element of the original `x` array ( `*(x + 2)` ) to the value of `y[1] + 1`. since `y` is initialized to point at the 3rd element, `y[1]` will point at the final element of the original x array.

`6 + 1` is assigned to the 3rd element of the `x` array, which `*y` refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Things to note:

- `*(x + 2)` is exactly the same as `x[2]`.
- `&x[2]` is exactly the same as `&(*(x + 2))` which is the same as `x + 2`.

So knowing that, let's rewrite the problem:

```
int x[4] = {0,2,4,6};
int *y = &x[2];
*(x + 2) = y[1] + 1;
```

And some more rewriting:

```
int x[4] = {0,2,4,6};
int *y = x + 2;
x[2] = *(y + 1) + 1;
```

Now, let's substitute `y` directly into the last equation:

```
int x[4] = {0,2,4,6};
int *y = x + 2;
x[2] = *((x + 2) + 1) + 1;
```

And clean it up:

```
int x[4] = {0,2,4,6};
int *y = x + 2;
x[2] = x[3] + 1;
```

So now, let's look at the problem:

1. `x[2]` is updated with the value of `x[3] + 1`
2. So `x[2]` is now 7.
3. So `x == {0, 2, 7, 6}`
4. y still points at the value at `x + 2`.
5. So `*y == 7`

Answer (score 0):

Let consider the code step by step.

Pointer y is initialized by the address of the third element of the array (indices start from 0)

```
y = &x[2];
```

So y points to 4. So `x[2]` and `y[0]` are equivalent expressions

`y[1]` is the next element after `y[0]` that is it is 6.

`y[1] + 1` will be equal to 7

`*( x + 2 )` is the same as `x[2]` So `x[2]` will be set to 7. At the same time y also points to 
`x[2]`. So `*y` will be equal to 7.

Answer (score 0):

The key components here are that the index operator returns y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfzCs.png) an actual int not an address. The same for the dereference operator *(x + 2).

```
int a = y[1]; // a = the value of the int after y[0]
int b = *(x + 2); // b = the value of x[2] note that the index operator is just shorthand, y[1] just means *(y + 1)
// int* c = y[1]; NOT LEGAL assignment of an int to an int*
// int* d = *(x + 2); NOT LEGAL assignment of an int to an int*
```

I've added a table here to hopefully help clarify:
[image: tabel]